# c# adding New Button Depending on the # of items in mySQLWorkbench

Tags: c#, mysql, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, c#-4.0

This code adds new buttons depending on the # of items saved on my items table.

mySQL WorkBench
[image]

[image]

I dont know why it keeps on duplicating my buttons. I just want to keep the buttons arranged into 4 columns.

```
    object[] itemDetail;
    object[] itemLi = itemsWS.searchItem("", "drinks", "all");
    int cleft = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < itemLi.Length; i++)
    {


        itemDetail = itemsWS.getItemInfo(itemLi[i].ToString());


        for (int x = 35; x < 537; x++)
        {
            Button myButton = new Button();
            myButton.Text = itemDetail[0].ToString();
            myButton.Top = cleft * 80;
            myButton.Left = 70;
            myButton.Location = new Point(x, cleft);
            myButton.Size = new Size(100, 60);
            tabPage1.Controls.Add(myButton);


            cleft = cleft + 15;
            //cleft = cleft + 1;

            x += 134;
        }

    }
```

Comment: You've got a nested loop. So it's adding the button for each item in the inner loop, then again for each item in the outer loop - So (4 times (5 times)) which is 20 times

Comment: So what do you prefer as a solution sir. Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I don't really understand why you need a loop to determine the new location...

Comment: I just want to make my GUI looked liked this.. [link]http://postimg.org/image/u70grrf4f/
please can you help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this:

```
int x = 35;
int cleft = 0;

foreach (var item in itemLi)
{
    Button myButton = new Button();
    myButton.Text = itemDetail[0].ToString();
    myButton.Top = cleft * 80;
    myButton.Left = 70;
    myButton.Location = new Point(x, cleft);
    myButton.Size = new Size(100, 60);
    tabPage1.Controls.Add(myButton);

    x += 134;
    // Check if x is greater than form size,
    // If so, resets x, and increments cleft
    if (x >= 537)
    {
        x == 35;
        cleft += 15
    }
}
```

I'm not exactly sure what `x` and `cleft` are doing, but you get the idea (hopefully)

Comment: This was helpful but with some minor issues. Thanks Ben!. The minor issues that i can only get 1 string in my MySQL Workbench. But Many Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You can also put `FlowLayoutPanel` inside the `Bread` tabpage, then just set the `Orientation` property of the `FlowLayoutPanel`, then do Ben's suggestion without the `Top`, `Left`, `Location`, `cleft`, and `x` stuff so you won't need to set the location of the Buttons.